# Price Set fields with Quantity per Option

Tags: civicontribute

We want to have our price set have options such as

A
B
C 
D

but we want to have a quantity field for each option

X  A
X  B
X  C
X  D

and have it calculated at the end of the form.

Is this possible or achievable with native CiviCRM functionality, or is there a way to adjust the code to suit our needs that has been done before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done if you set the Input field type to **Text/Numeric Quantity** when you create a price field.

You will need to create one price field per option.  There are two slight variations for this field type. Based on your question I think the following will work for you:

- If A costs $5, set the "**Price**" field to 5.00 and make the field's label something like "Number of $5 Widgets"

and so on for B, C and D.

The other option, mostly used for donations, can be found in our book in the section on  [membership pricesets](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/membership/membership-price-sets/). You will need to scroll down to the section on **Non-membership price fields**.